# ASP.NET Core Identity does not inject UserManager<ApplicationUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got an older asp.net core identity database, and I want to map a new project (a web api) to it.

Just for the test, I copied the Models folder, and the ApplicationUser file from the previous project (ApplicationUser simply inherits from IdentityUser, no changes whatsoever) - doing DB first seems to be a bad idea.

I'm registering Identity in ConfigureServices (but I'm not adding it to the pipeline since my only intention is to use the UserStore)

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My expectation is that now

```
     UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

...should be automatically injected into constructors.

However, when adding the following code to a controller
        private UserManager _userManager;

```
    public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

... every call to the api ends with an exception:
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Removing the "injection" code results in smoothly running web api that can accept requests.

It's hard to debug as this occurs before any of my code is reached. Any idea why this is occurring?

P.S. After enabling all exceptions from the Exception Settings window I got this one:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Namespace.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Namespace.Models.
>   ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole,Namespace.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String]'.

Comment: add full server error

Comment: When I had this error, the problem was my ApplicationDbContext was not derived from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>. It was just derived from IdentityDbContext without the generic type ApplicationUser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have the `app.UseIdentity();` call in the `Configure` method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                       IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        /*...*/
        app.UseIdentity();
       /*...*/          
    }
```

**EDIT**
   Do you also have this line before the `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` line?

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

 }
```

This should work OK. Also please check if `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext`.

Comment: I mentioned above that I didn't (since I don't intend to use it for authentication - only userstores). However, even after adding it experimentally the result is the same.

Comment: Your edit fixed it and now I'm embarrassed. I'll hide my face for the rest of the day...

Comment: Mihail mentions adding app.UseIdentity(). This has been deprecated in CORE 2.0. The method now is app.UseAuthentication(). Hope this helps.

Comment: `UseAuthentication()` doesn't seem to register these managers either.

Comment: What if I don't use a db context?

Comment: @Mihail Stancescu   so does it mean that `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` inject `UserManager<T>`?

Answer (score 4):

DI container is unable to resolve a dependency. Add it to the services collection

```
services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

You should also familiarize yourself with the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity)

Comment: It's exactly this documentation that claims that everything is available via DI after using services.AddIdentity(), which doesn't work unfortunately.

Tried this solution, in addition to adding transient user stores, password validators and all visible dependencies in the UserStore constructor - still nothing.

Comment: Ok understood. Can you add a [mcve] of the problem so that we can reproduce your problem and be in a position to provide better answers

Answer (score -1):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
...
var identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(user =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                user.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                user.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                user.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                user.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                user.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            });
            identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(identityBuilder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), identityBuilder.Services);
            identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    ...
}
```