# System.AggregateException exception while attempting to register a service in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception

I have made an `ISignUp interface` which is implemented by the `SignUp class` to create a new user. I am using **Dependancy Injection (DI)**. The issue is that I cannot register this service. Instead of creating new users in the `SignUpController` directly, I rather prefer calling a helper class via the `Interface` it implements.

I am sure I am missing something here. Let me post the `code` and the `exception` so that someone may point out what I am missing.

Project Details:

```
ASP.NET CORE 3.1
```

I will appreciate help in pointing out the issue here.

**Below is the ISignUp interface:**

> ```
> public interface ISignUp
> {
>     public Task<bool> IsUserCreatedAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password);
> }
> ```

**Below is the SignUp class implementing the ISignUp Interface:**

> ```
> public class SignUp : ISignUp
> {
>     private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
>
>     public SignUp(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
>     {
>         userManager = _userManager;
>     }
>
>     public async Task<bool> IsUserCreatedAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
>     {
>         // create a new user account
>         var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
>
>         // check result
>         if (result.Succeeded)
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Below is the SignUpController:**

> ```
> public class SignUpController : Controller
> {
>     private readonly ISignUp signUp;
>
>     public SignUpController(ISignUp _signUp)
>     {
>         signUp = _signUp;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Below checking if the user is created:**

> ```
>   // create new user
>   var userCreated = await signUp.IsUserCreatedAsync(user, model.Password);
>
>   // check result
>   if (userCreated)
>   {
>      // user created, log them in
>   }
> ```

**Registering the service in the StartUp.cs Class:**

> ```
>   // registering an ISignUp service and its implementation
>   services.AddScoped<ISignUp, SignUp>();
> ```

When I build and run, I get this exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: School_ERP_Software.Helpers.Interfaces.ISignUp Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: School_ERP_Software.Helpers.Implementation.SignUp': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[School_ERP_Software.Database.Model.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'School_ERP_Software.Helpers.Implementation.SignUp'.)'

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: From the error message it looks like UserManager is not registered

Comment: Please don't break the question's formatting. It's impossible to read the exception as is. That is the *most important information* in this question

Comment: nobody ever reads the exception messages :(

Comment: *Have* you added Identity to the services? The error complains that `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` isn't registered

Comment: Same as what @Athanasios said. Let me do that

Comment: I was missing this line of code:            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SoftwareDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: I appreciate all your suggestions which drove the issue home. Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have on constructor here:

```
public class SignUp : ISignUp
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    public SignUp(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
    {
        userManager = _userManager;
    }
```

The framework, tries to initialize the `SignUp` object with the only constructor it can find, which is the one above.

It does not know what value to provide, as you have not resolved this dependency for the DI container in your configuration, so you get the error above, hence the error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1

You need to register the `UserManager` service to get rid of the exception.

Check [ASP.NET Core Identity does not inject UserManager<ApplicationUser>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679217/asp-net-core-identity-does-not-inject-usermanagerapplicationuser)

Comment: Let me try your recommendation and also follow that link

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as accepted because it was more explanatory and the link you provided made me realize a piece of code I was missing. I appreciate your time and solution.