# how can I access usermanager in ASP.NET Core MVC webbapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, usermanager

I try to access usermanager in order to find a user. But struggling to figure out how this should be done. Here is what I have so far:

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

`LoginController`:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public LoginController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("user@home.se");
        //return View();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get an error in `LoginController` when initiate the `LoginController`:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'WebSite.Controllers.LoginController'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show where you are registering the identity service?

Comment: I think there was the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679217/asp-net-core-identity-does-not-inject-usermanagerapplicationuser

Comment: @JHBonarius this is the only code I have so far.... Can you show me what I need to add?

Comment: ??Are you just trying random code snippets you find? Maybe you should start looking for good guides. E.g. Microsoft has very good documentation nowadays: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity).

Comment: You also might want to read how to add EFCore to ASP.Net [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0). You don't need call configurationbuilder in ASP.net if you're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

I think that u r missing in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and then u can configure options

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});
```

and

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

Comment: It worked if i added builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); I was not able to add app.UseIdentity(); program.cs could not resolve that..